# Unexpected token 'accessRule' in expression or statement

Tags: powershell

The `Write-Host` cmdlet works fine, but when I try to pipe to `Out-File` it throws an error.

> Unexpected token 'accessRule' in expression or statement.

```
foreach($accessRule in $acl.Access)
{
Write-Host $accessRule.IdentityReference $accessRule.FileSystemRights
$accessRule.IdentityReference $accessRule.FileSystemRights| Out-File -Encoding Ascii -append $Report
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's because `Write-Host` just takes all arguments after it to output. Turn your output into one string first before sending it to Out-File:

```
foreach($accessRule in $acl.Access) {
    Write-Host $accessRule.IdentityReference $accessRule.FileSystemRights
    "$($accessRule.IdentityReference) $($accessRule.FileSystemRights)"|
         Out-File -Encoding Ascii -append $Report
}
```

Comment: Vote++.  Or pipe through Out-String.

Comment: My hero!   Thank you!

Comment: @yazzu If the answer worked for you, it's best practice to accept it.